# Express JS mongoDB async await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, mongoose

Can anyone help me where is the problem view is generated before mongoose get data from database. I already use await but its not waiting for response.

```
router.get('/', async(req, res, next)=> {
    try{
        const products = await Product.find({});
        res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Express',products });
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

});
```

Comment: How did you conclude that it's not waiting for response ?

Comment: I need view render after get all Product information

Comment: Try logging products before rendering using `console.log`

Answer (score 1):

Imao you tried to do somethins like this:

```
  router.get('/', async(req, res, next)=> {
      let products
      try{
          products = await Product.find({});
      }catch(e){
          console.log(e);
      }

      res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Express',products });
  });
```

But as I know the reason to use such syntax is cristmas tree of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
router.get('/', async(req, res, next)=> {
    try{
        Product.find({}).then(products => {
          res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Express',products });
        });
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

});
```